# Does charactermarkersymbol work differently in linux?

Tags: arcobjects, java, linux, eclipse

I have just started working in GIS. i am trying to project an aeroplane glyph font (character index=111) using **charactermarkersymbol** but unable to do it in linux. 
I am getting the same spherical projection for different character index values.
I am able to create a **simplemarkersymbol** and all the shapes provided like tetra, cone,diamond are projected. 
But, for various font styles all i am getting in charactermarkersymbol is a sphere. below is the code snippet. 
  I am working in a linux machine and **i'm not sure whether linux supports all these glyph fonts or not**. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
   try {

                IRgbColor color = new RgbColor();
                color.setRed(255);
                color.setGreen(0);
                color.setBlue(0);
                SimpleMarker3DSymbol sym =new SimpleMarker3DSymbol();
                sym.setStyle(esriSimple3DMarkerStyle.esriS3DMSTetra);


                StdFont font = new StdFont();
                font.setName("ESRI Default Marker");
                font.setSize(36);

                CharacterMarkerSymbol characterMarkerSymbol = new CharacterMarkerSymbol();
               characterMarkerSymbol.setAngle(90);

                characterMarkerSymbol.setColor(color);
               characterMarkerSymbol.setFont(font);
               characterMarkerSymbol.setCharacterIndex(111);
                characterMarkerSymbol.setSize(36);








                IMarkerSymbol imSym = characterMarkerSymbol;

                imSym.setColor(color);
                imSym.setSize(500);

                IMarkerElement mkElem = new MarkerElement();
                mkElem.setSymbol(imSym);
```

Comment: what software are you using? Have you installed that font on your Linux machine?

Comment: i am using ArcGis in Eclipse helios.the font style is supposed to be a part of ESRI default Marker. I am unable to understand how to install a font in /etc/fonts and then use it. i changed the font style to preinstalled sans-serif, Arial, lucida etc but still got the sphere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was unable to add a `CharacterMarkerSymbol` hence, i used a `Marker3dSymbol` and attatched a `.3ds` file to it. That has done the job perfectly, as well as provided a better alternative visually